# Convert Indian currency to Russian currency using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using this regex to convert number to display like Russian currency format.
Here is my code

```
var price = "12,000.50";
price = price.replace(/[,]+/g, '');
return price.replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1.");
```

But this code convert like this : "12.000.50", instead of it should be like "12.000,50".

Does any one know about his, how to solve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
price.replace(/(\.|,)/g, function(x){return {',': '.', '.': ','}[x]})
```

Comment: Great. Can use same for converting Russian to US? i.e. from "1.00.000,50" to "1,00,000.50" ?

Comment: If you have many locales I do recommend you to take a look at some number parsing|formatting lib. NumeralJS is good one IMHO http://numeraljs.com/

Comment: I assume 3 === many :) It is always better to have well tested bullet proof solution. Unless you have some strict requirement not to use NIH code.

Comment: Yes, but in my case i have vise a versa only.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function called `number_format()` that is forked from PHP to Javascript by the [PHPJS](http://locutus.io) team.

```
function number_format (number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {

  number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '')
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number
  var prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals)
  var sep = (typeof thousandsSep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousandsSep
  var dec = (typeof decPoint === 'undefined') ? '.' : decPoint
  var s = ''

  var toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
    var k = Math.pow(10, prec)
    return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
      .toFixed(prec)
  }

  // @todo: for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.')
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep)
  }
  if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || ''
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0')
  }

  return s.join(dec)
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
 var number = 19883.50;
 var formatted = number_format(number, 2, ".", ",");
```

### Snippet:

```js
function number_format (number, decimals, decPoint, thousandsSep) {

  number = (number + '').replace(/[^0-9+\-Ee.]/g, '')
  var n = !isFinite(+number) ? 0 : +number
  var prec = !isFinite(+decimals) ? 0 : Math.abs(decimals)
  var sep = (typeof thousandsSep === 'undefined') ? ',' : thousandsSep
  var dec = (typeof decPoint === 'undefined') ? '.' : decPoint
  var s = ''

  var toFixedFix = function (n, prec) {
    var k = Math.pow(10, prec)
    return '' + (Math.round(n * k) / k)
    .toFixed(prec)
  }

  // @todo: for IE parseFloat(0.55).toFixed(0) = 0;
  s = (prec ? toFixedFix(n, prec) : '' + Math.round(n)).split('.')
  if (s[0].length > 3) {
    s[0] = s[0].replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, sep)
  }
  if ((s[1] || '').length < prec) {
    s[1] = s[1] || ''
    s[1] += new Array(prec - s[1].length + 1).join('0')
  }

  return s.join(dec)
}






var number = 19883.50;
var formatted = number_format(number, 2, ",", ".");

console.log(formatted);
```